# XML difference using xquery in marklogic

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic, difference

I am looking for a similar XML difference algorithm in Xquery
that is similar to what xdiff.jar does in Java. On passing 2 XML
documents which follow the same schema I expect the Xquery to specify
what were the nodes/elements which have been added and what are the
nodes/elements deleted or modified. Any change in the sequence is to be
ignored. I would say its more of a logical difference that I expect
between the two XML documents.

For eg. Lets say the XML A is the initial version of a XML and XML B is
updated version of XML A, I should be able to prepare a report on which
I should be able to find out what are all the new XML tags which have
been added, what XML tags have been modified and what XML tags have been
deleted.

Comment: Please respecify with examples of what changes are to be expected. New elements? Changes in element names? Text nodes? Attribute (values)? Comments, processing instructions?

Comment: I concur with Jens. Being unfamiliar with xdiff.jar (can't find it on internet either) an example of what xdiff returns would help.

Comment: PS: if you are really fond of xdiff.jar, you could create a HTTP service in Java that discloses the xdiff functionality, and call that with xdmp:http-get of xdmp:http-post. You could also look at MLJAM (http://developer.marklogic.com/code/mljam) which provides a nice wrapper to access Java-code from MarkLogic.

Answer (score 1):

For that particular use-case you might try an approach using `xdmp:path` plus a traditional LCS diff. The `xdmp:path` code would produce a sequence of unique paths, and diffing those would show you which paths are new or deleted.

Here's how you might generate the input to the LCS diff: this returns an ordered sequence of every unique non-positional XPath in `$input`.

```
for $path in distinct-values(
  for $p in xdmp:path($input/descendant-or-self::*)
  return replace($p, '\[\d+\]', ''))
order by $path
return $path
```

Diffing two of these sequences should show you which paths have changed.

Implementing an LCS diff in XQuery is complicated, because the usual implementation of LCS uses two-dimensional arrays and XQuery does not have those. You might use a single `json:array` to simulate a two-dimensional one. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem for more about the algorithm.